# Is there a way I can determine which row I am on in a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, .net, foreach

I have this code:

```
foreach (var row in App.cardSetWithWordCounts)
{
   details.Children.Add(new SeparatorTemplate());
   // do some tasks for every row 
   // in this part of the loop ...
}
```

I would like to not do the adding of a `SeparatorTemplate` BUT I would like to do the other tasks on the first run of the `foreach`. Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can do this?

I want to execute the rest of the code in the `foreach` but not the line adding the template on the first time around.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to skip the first row, you can use `Skip`:

```
foreach (var row in App.cardSetWithWordCounts.Skip(1))
```

If you want to know the exact row number, use the `Select` overload:

```
foreach (var x in App.cardSetWithWordCounts.Select((r, i) => new { Row = r, Index = i })
{
    // use x.Row and x.Index
}
```

Comment: Linq is so useful, isn't it. Life without `IEnumerable` just wasn't the same.

Comment: Sorry maybe I am not clear.  I want to execute the rest of the code in the foreach but not the line adding the template on the first time around.

Comment: So, you can check if `x.Index == 0` for the first loop, right? Execute your code accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The simpliest would be:

```
bool isFirstRun = true;
foreach (var row in App.cardSetWithWordCounts)
{
    if(isFirstRun)
        isFirstRun = false;
    else
        details.Children.Add(new SeparatorTemplate());

    // do some tasks for every row 
    // in this part of the loop ...    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Skip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.skip?view=netframework-4.7.2) method for this purpose:

```
foreach (var row in App.cardSetWithWordCounts.Skip(1))
```

Update:

```
foreach (var row in App.cardSetWithWordCounts.Select((c, index) => new { Row = c, Index = index })
{
    if(row.Index != 0)
}
```

Just don't forget to add the following line to your `using` directives:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Sorry maybe I am not clear.  I want to execute the rest of the code in the foreach but not the line adding the template on the first time around.

Answer (score 1):

```
var firstRow = true;

foreach(var row in App.cardSetWithWordCounts)
{
    if(firstRow) 
    {
        firstRow = false;
    }
    else
    {
        // rest of the code here
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create an Extention method.

`Action` second parameter is the iterator index.

```
public static class ExtenstionArray
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Action< T, int> action)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (T item in sequence)
        {
            action(item,i);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Then use like this.

```
App.cardSetWithWordCounts.ForEach((i, idx)=>{
    if(idx == 0){
        details.Children.Add(new SeparatorTemplate());
    }
    // other logic
});
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GHzzFY)